# How do you actually configure DHCP in MaaS in Raring?

Tags: 13.04, dhcp, maas

All the docs say is

> If you are using MAAS to control DHCP, you need to set this via the web interface.

But I see no mention of DHCP in the web interface. What exactly do you click on to configure DHCP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out:

1. Click on the unlabeled gear icon.
2. Under the Cluster controllers section, click the small grey edit button.
3. Under the Interfaces section, add or edit a network interface.
4. Set Management to Manage DHCP.

Comment: In precise i can not see Cluster controllers under the gear icon .

Comment: this was the answer for me

Answer (score 2):

Wes, thanks for asking this question and for answering it! You led me down the right path. I'll detail what I did after I followed the steps you gave. I initially tried to get this working by just installing the maas-dhcp package, but it would start b/c a bunch of conf files were missing.

First I followed your steps:

- Click on the unlabeled gear icon
- Under the Cluster controllers
  section, click the small grey edit button.
- Under the Interfaces
  section, add or edit a network interface.
- Set Management to Manage DHCP

After I entered all the details for the DHCP server, I restarted MAAS and it wouldn't work. So, I went back and noticed on that edit page for the region controller it said:

> If you enable DHCP management, you will need to install the
>   'maas-dhcp' package on this cluster controller. Similarly, you will
>   need to install the 'maas-dns' package on this region controller to be
>   able to enable DNS management.

So I did:

```
sudo apt-get install maas-dhcp maas-dns
```

And I finally got a node to get an address from it.

Comment: Update: The above is all correct and true, nodes can get an IP address via PXE booting, but they don't show up. Front page of MAAS still says "0 nodes in MAAS". To be clear, I can boot a node to a Raring CD and find the MAAS server. The node shuts down, but doesn't show up in the MAAS web ui.

I'm using MAAS on Raring Ringtail with a Virtualbox MAAS Server and Virtualbox nodes. I'm booting the nodes to the same Raring Ringtail Server CD that I used to create the MAAS Server.

Comment: Please add this detail to your answer! [Leaving a half-answer as a comment](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments) can often cause more harm than good. Thanks.